# Which is the right way to use delegate?

Tags: c#

I would like two know if there is a difference between the two, and if they are the same which one is the better practice?

Class one:

```
Action onDeath;
public void RegisterDeath(Action callback) 
{
    onDeath += callback;
}
```

And then let other class 2 to subscribe to this RegisterDeath method?
Or is it better to make:

```
public Action onDeath;
//or even
public event Action onDeath;
```

And subscribe to this public delegade without clutter in the main class?
If there is a difference could someone explain it briefly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you publicly expose a delegate, everyone can reset the invocation list or even invoke the delegate:

```
class Test
{
    public static Action MyAction;
}

Test.MyAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Resets invocation list
Test.MyAction(); // Invokes delegate
```

In most cases, this is unwanted behavior. That's why C# has the `event` keyword. Events can only be subscribed (using `+=`) or unsubscribed (using `-=`).

```
class Test
{
    public static event Action MyAction;
}

Test.MyAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Not allowed
Test.MyAction(); // Not allowed
Test.MyAction += () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Only this is allowed
```

Using your own method `RegisterDeath` could give you even more control of how or when the delegate can be (un)subscribed. In many cases, a simple `event` should be sufficient, though.